# Why does Excel have multiple escape characters and what are they used for?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've always used...

> '

...but just found out while reading through a couple of other Q&A's here that there are additionally...

> ~
>   \

Why are there multiple escape characters and what are they used for?

Comment: [How can I escape special characters in cell formatting in Excel - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/612434/how-can-i-escape-special-characters-in-cell-formatting-in-excel)

Comment: [vlookup - Working with "~" in excel - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/603266/working-with-in-excel)

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill those two posts are actually the posts I was referring to above!  I'm not very clear on the differences between them, and what necessitates three types of escapes?  Just curious about the correct usage for them respectively -- assuming they *do* somehow differ from one another.

Comment: I did see, if I am understanding correctly, that the ' character will escape the cell contents "as text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reviewing my past unanswered questions, I thought I'd come back and take a shot at answering this one myself.

`'` (when prefixed to direct cell inputs) will convert the output of the cell contents to be displayed `As Text`.  Functionally, this will achieve the equivalent effect as escaping certain characters in terms of *visual/typographical output*; <s>this does in turn make the cell data harder to work with for formulations or computations</s> in the time since I've written this answer, newer versions of Excel have gained functions, e.g., `value()`, etc., that improve QoL when working across mixed data types and/or formatting.

`\` acts as an escape character for the immediately subsequent character entered, but is particularly used in cell data type formatting or custom formatting rather than for explicit inputs; this enables the user to escape certain characters reserved by Excel for special formatting functions, e.g., the `:` in cell formatting set as "#:#" normally outputs the resultant data as a `Time` data type, and would need to be escaped as "#\:#" to mitigate this behavior

`~` acts as an escape character for *actual* cell-input characters, and will behave much in the same way as described above: namely, it will process the immediately subsequent character input as a literal (or for AHK users, think of it as `SendRaw`).

Hope that explains with more clarity what the respective usage cases are and how they differ from one another!

### Related Posts & Acknowledgements:

- [How can I escape special characters in cell formatting in Excel - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/612434/how-can-i-escape-special-characters-in-cell-formatting-in-excel)
- [vlookup - Working with "~" in excel - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/603266/working-with-in-excel)

And my thanks to @DavidPostill for including the actual reference links.